# Simple calculator - how to stop button click after one click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do simple calculator in JavaScript. My code is far from perfect, but for now I just want to fix bugs. 
First I can't figure out, how to stop operators from propagating. I mean for example I click 1 + 1 = everything is ok and I get result correctly.
The problem is when I click more than once on operator and I can add a lot of them. How I can disable/stop operator after one click. I was tried different approaches: count button click, add  for every number and operator, but not avail.

There is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EASY Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calculator.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/calculator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
// creating wrapper for all div's and append to HTML body tag
var myWraper = document.createElement('div');
myWraper.id = 'container';
document.body.appendChild(myWraper);

//function creating div's for calculator and buttons
function divCalc(divClass, btnInnerHTML) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = divClass;
    div.innerHTML = btnInnerHTML;
    return div;
}
// array of calclulator div's
var rowsCalc = [
    divCalc('row1', '<button class="btnDel">Del</button><button class="btnOper" value="%">%</button><button class="btnOper" value="+">+</button>'),
    divCalc('row2', '<button class="btnNum" value="7">7</button><button class="btnNum" value="8">8</button><button class="btnNum" value="9">9</button><button class="btnOper" value="-">-</button>'),
    divCalc('row3', '<button class="btnNum" value="4">4</button><button class="btnNum" value="5">5</button><button class="btnNum" value="6">6</button><button class="btnOper" value="*">*</button>'),
    divCalc('row4', '<button class="btnNum" value="1">1</button><button class="btnNum" value="2">2</button><button class="btnNum" value="3">3</button><button class="btnOper" value="/">/</button>'),
    divCalc('row5', '<button class="btnNum" value="0">0</button><button class="btnNum" value=".">.</button><button class="btnEql" value="=">=</button>')
];

//function creating div's for page
function divPage(divID) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = divID;
    return div;
}
// array of page div's
var rowsPage = [
    divPage('result'),
    divPage('main')
];

// using createDocumentFragment() method append all div's at once to page
var docFragPage = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < rowsPage.length; i += 1) {
    docFragPage.appendChild(rowsPage[i]);
}
myWraper.appendChild(docFragPage); // appends all div's at once to 'container' div

// the same as above for calculator div's
var docFragCalc = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < rowsCalc.length; i += 1) {
    docFragCalc.appendChild(rowsCalc[i]);
}
rowsPage[1].appendChild(docFragCalc); // appends all div's at once to 'main' div

//append event listener
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // event only triger when pressed on buttons
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        // variable for output
        var output = document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML;

        // trigered when 'Del' button is clicked
        if (e.target.className === "btnDel") {
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = '';

        }
        // trigered when numbers are clicked
        if (e.target.className === 'btnNum') {
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += e.target.value;
        }
        // trigered when operators are clicked
        if (e.target.className === 'btnOper') {
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += e.target.value;
        }
        // trigered when equality button is clicked
        if (e.target.className === 'btnEql') {
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = eval(output);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: disable the button until other buttons are clicked again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to check what was the last character. If it was an operation different from the one that was clicked you replace it with the new one. If it is equals you prevent from duplicating it.
Try this:

```js
var myWraper = document.createElement('div');
myWraper.id = 'container';
document.body.appendChild(myWraper);

//function creating div's for calculator and buttons
function divCalc(divClass, btnInnerHTML){
    var div = document.createElement('div');    
    div.className = divClass;
    div.innerHTML = btnInnerHTML;
    return div;
}
// array of calclulator div's
var rowsCalc = [
    divCalc('row1', '<button class="btnDel">Del</button><button class="btnOper" value="%">%</button><button class="btnOper" value="+">+</button>'),
    divCalc('row2', '<button class="btnNum" value="7">7</button><button class="btnNum" value="8">8</button><button class="btnNum" value="9">9</button><button class="btnOper" value="-">-</button>'),
    divCalc('row3', '<button class="btnNum" value="4">4</button><button class="btnNum" value="5">5</button><button class="btnNum" value="6">6</button><button class="btnOper" value="*">*</button>'),
    divCalc('row4', '<button class="btnNum" value="1">1</button><button class="btnNum" value="2">2</button><button class="btnNum" value="3">3</button><button class="btnOper" value="/">/</button>'),
    divCalc('row5', '<button class="btnNum" value="0">0</button><button class="btnNum" value=".">.</button><button class="btnEql" value="=">=</button>')
];

//function creating div's for page
function divPage(divID){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = divID;
    return div;
}
// array of page div's
var rowsPage = [
    divPage('result'),
    divPage('main')    
];

// using createDocumentFragment() method append all div's at once to page
var docFragPage = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < rowsPage.length; i +=1) {
  docFragPage.appendChild(rowsPage[i]); 
}
myWraper.appendChild(docFragPage); // appends all div's at once to 'container' div

// the same as above for calculator div's
var docFragCalc = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < rowsCalc.length; i +=1) {
    docFragCalc.appendChild(rowsCalc[i]);   
}
rowsPage[1].appendChild(docFragCalc); // appends all div's at once to 'main' div

var disable = false;

//append event listener
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // event only triger when pressed on buttons
    if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
        // variable for output
        if(disable){
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = '';
        disable = false;
        }
        var output = document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML;       

        // trigered when 'Del' button is clicked
        if(e.target.className === "btnDel"){
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = '';

        }
        // trigered when numbers are clicked
        if(e.target.className === 'btnNum'){           
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += e.target.value;      
        }
        // trigered when operators are clicked
        if(e.target.className === 'btnOper'){
        //operations on a list
        var charsToSearch = ["+","-","*","/","%"];
            //check what was the last char
            var lastChar =  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML.slice(-1);
            //if last char was a different operation, replace it with new
            if(e.target.value != lastChar){
            if(charsToSearch.indexOf(lastChar) != -1){
                var str = document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
                str = str + e.target.value; 
                document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = str;
                return;
              }              
            }
            switch(lastChar){
              case '+':
                return;
              case '-':
                return;
              case '*':
                return;
              case '/':
                return;
            }
                document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += e.target.value;
        }
        // trigered when equality button is clicked
        if(e.target.className === 'btnEql'){  
     
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = eval(output);  
               disable = true;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: That was spot on! I wouldn't figure out myself, I'm still a baby programmer :-/ It took me while to understand everything what you did and I wouldn't without Chrome and web developer tool :-) I brokepointed you code, step by step.

Comment: one more thing.. I don't get that part of the code:
`// variable for output
        if(disable){
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = '';
        disable = false;
        }`

Comment: @MartinT this will check if user's last action was to click on the `=` button. If it was, it clear all value, sso thw user doesn't need to click on `Del` everytime to initiate a new operation.

Comment: @MartinT don't forget to accept this as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: I missed that bit, about clearing all values. Once again thx for helping me out! Now I need to fix the rest of bugs by my own :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var myWraper = document.createElement('div');
myWraper.id = 'container';
document.body.appendChild(myWraper);

//function creating div's for calculator and buttons
function divCalc(divClass, btnInnerHTML){
    var div = document.createElement('div');    
    div.className = divClass;
    div.innerHTML = btnInnerHTML;
    return div;
}
// array of calclulator div's
var rowsCalc = [
    divCalc('row1', '<button class="btnDel">Del</button><button class="btnOper" value="%">%</button><button class="btnOper" value="+">+</button>'),
    divCalc('row2', '<button class="btnNum" value="7">7</button><button class="btnNum" value="8">8</button><button class="btnNum" value="9">9</button><button class="btnOper" value="-">-</button>'),
    divCalc('row3', '<button class="btnNum" value="4">4</button><button class="btnNum" value="5">5</button><button class="btnNum" value="6">6</button><button class="btnOper" value="*">*</button>'),
    divCalc('row4', '<button class="btnNum" value="1">1</button><button class="btnNum" value="2">2</button><button class="btnNum" value="3">3</button><button class="btnOper" value="/">/</button>'),
    divCalc('row5', '<button class="btnNum" value="0">0</button><button class="btnNum" value=".">.</button><button class="btnEql" value="=">=</button>')
];

//function creating div's for page
function divPage(divID){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = divID;
    return div;
}
// array of page div's
var rowsPage = [
    divPage('result'),
    divPage('main')    
];

// using createDocumentFragment() method append all div's at once to page
var docFragPage = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < rowsPage.length; i +=1) {
  docFragPage.appendChild(rowsPage[i]); 
}
myWraper.appendChild(docFragPage); // appends all div's at once to 'container' div

// the same as above for calculator div's
var docFragCalc = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < rowsCalc.length; i +=1) {
    docFragCalc.appendChild(rowsCalc[i]);   
}
rowsPage[1].appendChild(docFragCalc); // appends all div's at once to 'main' div

var disable = false;

//append event listener
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // event only triger when pressed on buttons
    if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
    
        // variable for output
 
        var output = document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML;       

        // trigered when 'Del' button is clicked
        if(e.target.className === "btnDel"){
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = '';

        }
        // trigered when numbers are clicked
        if(e.target.className === 'btnNum'){  
        disable = false
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += e.target.value;      
        }
        // trigered when operators are clicked
        if(e.target.className === 'btnOper'){ 
        if(!disable){
          document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += e.target.value;
          disable = true;
        }
             
                
        }
        // trigered when equality button is clicked
        if(e.target.className === 'btnEql'){  
            
          
            
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = eval(output);  
    
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any concern.

Comment: which test did it fail?

Comment: if you click many times on any operators it will propagate as long as you will click. I want to stop after one click of any operators. thx

Comment: it worked for one operator, but I couldn't use others. If I press '+' for and then '-' it didn't work. Thank you anyway!